# c# switch statement has unreachable code warning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, warnings

So my Switch statement seems to be wrong but I can't figure out why. Could Someone maybe help? it says that the break statement is unreachable code

```
switch (collisionTable[collisionIndex]) //Collision behavior
            {
                case 0: //Passable tile
                    nextPos.y = 0;
                    return true;
                    break;
                case 1: //Impassable tile
                    nextPos.y = 0;
                    return false;
                    break;
                case 2: //Slope tile
                    if (direction == Vector3.forward)
                    {
                        nextPos.y = 0.5f;
                        terrainLevel = 1.5f;
                    }
                    if (direction == Vector3.back)
                    {
                        nextPos.y = -0.5f;
                        terrainLevel = 1.5f;
                    }
                    return true;
                    break;
                default: //Fallback
                    return false;
```

Comment: In `return true; break;` the `break` is unreachable

Answer (score 4):

The **break** statement is not required in all of the cases because the return always executes.

Code execution will never reach the break statement so what The compiler is doing is issuing a warning that if you include the break statement after the return statement the code is not reachable (but the code will still compile);

Bottom line, remove the break after the return statements and the warning will disappear

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. You don't need a `break` statement after you type `return`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `break` after `return`, because `return` means that you return from whichever function your `switch` is on, back to where it is called.